# How to numerically order array of delimited strings in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm in a little bit of a bind.  I'm working with a legacy system that contains a bunch of delimited strings which I need to parse.  Unfortunately, the strings need to be ordered based on the first part of the string.  The array looks something like

```
array[0] = "10|JohnSmith|82";
array[1] = "1|MaryJane|62";
array[2] = "3|TomJones|77";
```

So I'd like the array to order to look like

```
array[0] = "1|MaryJane|62";
array[1] = "3|TomJones|77";
array[2] = "10|JohnSmith|82";
```

I thought about doing a 2 dimensional array to grab the first part and leave the string in the second part, but can I mix types in a two dimensional array like that?

I'm not sure how to handle this situation, can anyone help?  Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Call `Array.Sort`, but passing in a custom implementation of `IComparer<string>`:

```
// Give it a proper name really :)
public class IndexComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string first, string second)
    {
        // I'll leave you to decide what to do if the format is wrong
        int firstIndex = GetIndex(first);
        int secondIndex = GetIndex(second);
        return firstIndex.CompareTo(secondIndex);
    }

    private static int GetIndex(string text)
    {
        int pipeIndex = text.IndexOf('|');
        return int.Parse(text.Substring(0, pipeIndex));
    }
}
```

Alternatively, convert from a string array into an array of custom types by splitting the string up appropriately. This will make life easier if you're going to do further work on the array, but if you *only* need to sort the values, then you might as well use the code above.

You did say that you need to parse the strings - so is there any particular reason why you'd want to parse them *before* sorting them?

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly!  (although I had to change the private method to below for some reason) 
private static int GetIndex(string text)

Comment: Sorry to not be clear, parsing is definitely post sort.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

```
        new[] {
            "10|JohnSmith|82",
            "1|MaryJane|62",
            "3|TomJones|77",
        }.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Split('|')[0]));
```

Comment: Just tried this out and it seemed to work well, I choose the other answer though to give me more flexibility, thanks!

Comment: One thing to note (not a criticism, just a difference) between OrderBy and Sort is that Sort does it in-place - it changes the contents of the array. OrderBy returns a new sequence which is ordered.

Answer (score 1):

Use an ArrayList (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist_methods(VS.80).aspx) so you can sort it.

Comment: Why would that help? Array already has sorting methods available on it.

Answer (score 1):

If the array is large, you will want to extract the initial integers all in one pass, so you are not parsing strings at every comparison.  IMO, you really want to encapsulate the information encoded in the strings into a class first.  Then sort the array of those objects.

Something like:

```
class Person {
  int Index { get; }
  string Name { get; }
  int Age { get; }  // just guessing the semantic meaning
}
```

So then:

1. Map your encoded string into an `ArrayList` of `Person` objects.
2. Then use `ArrayList.Sort(IComparer)` where your comparer only looks at the Index.

This will likely perform better than using parse in every comparison.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that Jon Skeet also suggested to parse first, then sort.  I support his answer.

Answer (score 0):

for lolz

```
Array.Sort(array, ((x,y) => (int.Parse(x.Split('|')[0]) < int.Parse(y.Split('|')[0])) ? -1 : (int.Parse(x.Split('|')[0]) > int.Parse(y.Split('|')[0])) ? 1 : 0));
```